# MediaPlayer is not stop playing when stop() method is calling

Tags: android, sharedpreferences, android-mediaplayer, alarmmanager, android-preferences

Hi i am creating an alarm where i have used RingtonePreference for selecting alarmtone.So when the user chose his ringtone it will be saved in sharedpreference and i can create a uri with the selected ringtone.

My app has a stop button in alarm ringing window.When alarm is ringing i want to stop the mediaplayer whenever i clicked the stop button.The code i used here is **player.stop();player.release();** My problem is it is not stop playing even if i clicked the stop button.pls help me.My full code is displayed below.

***Stop button code***

```
try
        {
            if(mp.isPlaying())
                mp.stop();

            mp.reset();//It requires again setDataSource for player object.
            mp.release();
            mp=null; // fixed typo.
        }
        catch(IllegalStateException e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

**Code for reading selected ringtone from Sharedpreference and setting to play using Mediaplayer**

```
  //reading preference value 
        SharedPreferences preferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this)
        String alarms = preferences.getString(getResources().getString(R.string.key_ringpref),"default ringtone");
        soundUri = Uri.parse(alarms);
        mp=MediaPlayer.create(getBaseContext(),soundUri);
        mp.setOnErrorListener(this);
        try 
        {
            mp.prepare();
            mp.setLooping(true);
        } catch (IllegalStateException e1) 
        {
            e1.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e1)
        {
            e1.printStackTrace();
        }
      mp.start();
```

Comment: There can be 2 problems if this code is not working. 1. Either your clickListener is not properly applied on the `Button`. 2. You should not call `reset()` after stopping the music

Comment: clicklistner has no problem because the finish() is called in button click.Let me check the other one

Comment: Always reset() not stop() the mediaplayer if you want to reuse its instance. Also do not call reset() after stop().

Comment: I removed the reset() and again the alarm is not stopping..

Comment: @AnishUbais Any solution on this? I'm having the same issue.